# What is the difference between a Relational and Non-Relational Database?

Tags: relational-database, non-relational-database

MySQL, PostgreSQL and MS SQL Server are relational database systems, and NoSQL, MongoDB, etc. are non-relational DBMSs.

What are the differences between the two types of system?

Comment: This is not homework...but today I was trying to explain the differences to a friend and kinda started coming up blank. So I figured I would search here and haven't found any satisfying explanations. So figured I would ask. The differences I was saying is that with RDBMS there are lots of tables and joins between the tables. NoSQL doesn't have multiple tables, it just has one table and uses key value pairs. Not sure if this is an accurate description, so I figured I would ask.

Comment: I found these answers unhelpful because they spend too much time talking about how difficult the question is without actually answering the question. After reading this blog post I think the main idea is nosql is better than sql dbs at scaling out ie becoming distributed when scaling up ie more compute power on a single machine is no longer an option https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2015/08/relational-databases-vs-non-relational-databases/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Relational databases have a mathematical basis (set theory, relational theory), which are distilled into SQL == Structured Query Language.

NoSQL's many forms (e.g. document-based, graph-based, object-based, key-value store, etc.) may or may not be based on a single underpinning mathematical theory.  As S. Lott has correctly pointed out, [hierarchical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database_model) data stores do indeed have a mathematical basis.  The same might be said for [graph databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory).

I'm not aware of a universal query language for NoSQL databases.

Comment: "have no such mathematical underpinnings"?  Really?  Hierarchical databases seemed pretty mathematical to me.  They were also relatively simple, by comparison.    I think the XML database folks have a pretty solid lock on what can (and cannot) be done in a hierarchical database.

Comment: Could be my ignorance or over-simplification at work here, S. Lott.  I'll look for a reference.

Comment: I'm no expert on the matter, but since they're all structured datastires I believe at least a subset of SQL can be applied to any model. For that matter, I actually like how Google has exposed a query language that's true to SQL for their Big Table http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html. Really made things much much easier.

Answer (score 48):

Hmm, not quite sure what your question is.

In the title you ask about Databases (DB), whereas in the body of your text you ask about Database Management Systems (DBMS). The two are completely different and require different answers.

A DBMS is a tool that allows you to access a DB.

Other than the data itself, a DB is the concept of how that data is structured.

So just like you can program with Oriented Object methodology with a non-OO powered compiler, or vice-versa, so can you set-up a relational database without an RDBMS or use an RDBMS to store non-relational data.

I'll focus on what Relational Database (RDB) means and leave the discussion about what systems do to others.

A relational database (the concept) is a data structure that allows you to link information from different 'tables', or different types of data buckets. A data bucket must contain what is called a key or index (that allows to uniquely identify any atomic chunk of data within the bucket). Other data buckets may refer to that key so as to create a link between their data atoms and the atom pointed to by the key.

A non-relational database just stores data without explicit and structured mechanisms to link data from different buckets to one another.

As to implementing such a scheme, if you have a paper file with an index and in a different paper file you refer to the index to get at the relevant information, then you have implemented a relational database, albeit quite a simple one. So you see that you do not even need a computer (of course it can become tedious very quickly without one to help), similarly you do not need an RDBMS, though arguably an RDBMS is the right tool for the job. That said there are variations as to what the different tools out there can do so choosing the right tool for the job may not be all that straightforward.

I hope this is layman terms enough and is helpful to your understanding.

Comment: "if you have a paper file with an index and in a different paper file you refer to the index to get at the relevant information, then you have implemented a relational database" very good example. Would be great if this is further expanded to explain primary key, foreign key etc.

Comment: One doesn't need to know about constraints or declare any or have any to declare (including PKs, CKs & FKs) to use a relational database. They're for integrity. Tables represent relation(ship)s. Join & other operators connect tables to get new tables whose relation(ship)s are combinations of argument tables' relation(ship)s. Also indexes are for implementation optimization & are irrelevant to a database/DBMS being relational to its users.

Answer (score 23):

Most of what you "know" is wrong.

First of all, as a few of the relational gurus routinely (and sometimes stridently) point out, SQL doesn't really fit nearly as closely with relational theory as many people think. Second, most of the differences in "NoSQL" stuff has relatively little to do with whether it's relational or not. Finally, it's pretty difficult to say how "NoSQL" differs from SQL because *both* represent a pretty wide range of possibilities.

The one major difference that you can count on is that almost anything that supports SQL supports things like triggers in the database itself -- i.e. you can design rules into the database proper that are intended to ensure that the data is always internally consistent. For example, you can set things up so your database asserts that a person *must* have an address. If you do so, anytime you add a person, it will basically force you to associate that person with some address. You might add a new address or you might associate them with some existing address, but one way or another, the person must have an address. Likewise, if you delete an address, it'll force you to either remove all the people currently at that address, or associate each with some other address. You can do the same for other relationships, such as saying every person must have a mother, every office must have a phone number, etc.

Note that these sorts of things are also guaranteed to happen atomically, so if somebody else looks at the database as you're adding the person, they'll either not see the person at all, or else they'll see the person *with* the address (or the mother, etc.)

Most of the NoSQL databases do *not* attempt to provide this kind of enforcement in the database proper. It's up to you, in the code that uses the database, to enforce any relationships necessary for your data. In most cases, it's also possible to see data that's only partially correct, so even if you have a family tree where every person is supposed to be associated with parents, there can be times that whatever constraints you've imposed won't really be enforced. Some will let you do that at will. Others guarantee that it only happens temporarily, though exactly how long it can/will last can be open to question.

Answer (score 10):

The relational database uses a formal system of predicates to address data. The underlying physical implementation is of no substance and can vary to optimize for certain operations, but it must always assume the [relational model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model). In layman's terms, that's just saying *I know exactly how many values (attributes) each row (tuple) in my table (relation) has and now I want to exploit the fact accordingly, thoroughly and to it's extreme.* That's the **true** nature of the beast.

Since we're obviously the generation that has had a relational upbringing, if you look at NoSQL database models from the perspective of the relational model, again in layman's terms, the first obvious difference is that no assumptions about the number of values a row can contain is ever made. This is really oversimplifying the matter and does not cleanly apply to the intricacies of the physical models of every NoSQL database, but it's the pinnacle of the relational model and the first assumption we have to leave behind or, if you'd rather, the biggest leap we have to make.

We can agree to two things that are true for every DBMS: it can store any kind of data and has enough mathematical underpinnings to make it possible to manage the data in any way imaginable. The reality is that you'll never want to make the mistake of putting any of the two points to the test, but rather just stick with what the actual DBMS was really made for. In layman's terms: **respect the beast within!**

*(Please note that I've avoided comparing the (obviously) well founded standards revolving around the relational model against the many flavors provided by NoSQL databases. If you'd like, consider NoSQL databases as an umbrella term for any DBMS that does not completely assume the relational model, in exclusion to everything else. The differences are too many, but that's the principal difference and the one I think would be of most use to you to understand the two.)*

Answer (score 6):

Try to explain this question in a level referring to a little bit technology

Take MongoDB and Traditional SQL for comparison, imagine the scenario of  posting a Tweet on Twitter. This tweet contains 9 pictures. How do you store this tweet and its corresponding pictures?

In terms of traditional relationship SQL, you can store the tweets and pictures in separate tables, and represent the connection through building a new table.

What's more, you can set a field which is an image type, and zip the 9 pictures into a binary document and store it in this field.

Using MongoDB, you could build a document like this (similar to the concept of a table in relational SQL):

```
{

"id":"XXX",

"user":"XXX",

"date":"xxxx-xx-xx",

"content":{

"text":"XXXX",

"picture":["p1.png","p2.png","p3.png"]

}
```

Therefore, in my opinion, the main difference is about how do you store the data and the storage level of the relationships between them.

In this example, the data is the tweet and the pictures. The different mechanism about storage level of relationship between them also play a important role in the difference between both.

I hope this small example helps show the difference between SQL and NoSQL (ACID and BASE).

Here's a link of picture about the goals of NoSQL from the Internet:

http://icamchuwordpress-wordpress.stor.sinaapp.com/uploads/2015/01/dbc795f6f262e9d01fa0ab9b323b2dd1_b.png

Comment: really good explaination, there is  link where i got first idea, i hop it might help some one. http://growthefuturenow.com/relational-vs-non-relational-database/

Answer (score 4):

The difference between relational and non-relational is exactly that.  The relational database architecture provides with constraints objects such as primary keys, foreign keys, etc that allows one to tie two or more tables in a relation.  This is good so that we normalize our tables which is to say split information about what the database represents into many different tables, once can keep the integrity of the data.

For example, say you have a series of table that houses information about an employee.  You could not delete a record from a table without deleting all the records that pertain to such record from the other tables.  In this way you implement data integrity.  The non-relational database doesn't provide this constraints constructs that will allow you to implement data integrity.

Unless you don't implement this constraint in the front end application that is utilized to populate the databases' tables, you are implementing a mess that can be compared with the wild west.

Answer (score 1):

First up let me start by saying why we need a database.

We need a database to help organise information in such a manner that we can retrieve that data stored in a efficient manner.

Examples of relational database management systems(SQL):

1)Oracle Database

2)SQLite

3)PostgreSQL

4)MySQL

5)Microsoft SQL Server

6)IBM DB2

Examples of non relational database management systems(NoSQL)

1)MongoDB

2)Cassandra

3)Redis

4)Couchbase

5)HBase

6)DocumentDB

7)Neo4j

Relational databases have normalized data, as in information is stored in tables in forms of rows and columns, and normally when data is in normalized form, it helps to reduce data redundancy, and the data in tables are normally related to each other, so when we want to retrieve the data, we can query the data by using join statements and retrieve data as per our need.This is suited when we want to have more writes, less reads, and not much data involved, also its really easy relatively to update data in tables than in non relational databases. Horizontal scaling not possible, vertical scaling possible to some extent.CAP(Consistency, Availability, Partition Tolerant), and ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Duration)compliance.

Let me show entering data to a relational database using PostgreSQL as an example.

First create a product table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_no integer,
    name text,
    price numeric
);
```

then insert the data

```
INSERT INTO products (product_no, name, price) VALUES (1, 'Cheese', 9.99);
```

Let's look at another different example:
[image]

Here in a relational database, we can link the student table and subject table using relationships, via foreign key, subject ID, but in a non relational database no need to have two documents, as no relationships, so we store all the subject details and student details in one document say student document, then data is getting duplicated, which makes updating records troublesome.

In non relational databases, there is no fixed schema, data is not normalized. no relationships between data is created, all data mostly put in one document. Well suited when handling lots of data, and can transfer lots of data at once, best where high amounts of reads and less writes, and less updates, bit difficult to query data, as no fixed schema. Horizontal and vertical scaling is possible.CAP (Consistency, Availability, Partition Tolerant)and BASE (Basically Available, soft state, Eventually consistent)compliance.

Let me show an example to enter data to a non relational database using Mongodb

```
db.users.insertOne({name: ‘Mary’, age: 28 , occupation: ‘writer’ })
db.users.insertOne({name: ‘Ben’ , age: 21})
```

Hence you can understand that to the database called db, and there is a collections called users, and document called insertOne to which we add data, and there is no fixed schema as our first record has 3 attributes, and second attribute has 2 attributes only, this is no problem in non relational databases, but this cannot be done in relational databases, as relational databases have a fixed schema.

Let's look at another different example

```
({Studname: ‘Ash’, Subname: ‘Mathematics’, LecturerName: ‘Mr. Oak’})
```

Hence we can see in non relational database we can enter both student details and subject details into one document, as no relationships defined in non relational databases, but here this way can lead to data duplication, and hence errors in updating can occur therefore.

Hope this explains everything

Answer (score -1):

In layman terms it's strongly structured vs unstructured, which implies that you have different degrees of adaptability for your DB.
Differences arise in indexation particularly as you need to ensure that a certain reference index can link to a another item -> this a relation. The more strict structure of relational DB comes from this requirement.

To note that NosDB apaprently provides both relational and non relational DBs and a way to query both http://www.alachisoft.com/nosdb/sql-cheat-sheet.html